# Storybook: "Element type is invalid" when using an alias

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

After I made "@" an alias for the src directory, Storybook began to spit the following error for all my components:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `unboundStoryFn`.

I didn't mix up default and named imports, and I didn't forget to export my components.
All worked perfectly fine before.

Storybook settings:

```
const path = require("path");

const toPath = (_path) => path.join(process.cwd(), _path);

module.exports = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y",
  ],
  framework: "@storybook/react",
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    return {
      ...config,
      resolve: {
        ...config.resolve,
        alias: {
          ...config.resolve.alias,
          // We need this for emotion to work inside storybook
          "@emotion/core": toPath("node_modules/@emotion/react"),
          "@emotion/styled": toPath("node_modules/@emotion/styled"),
          "@": toPath("src"),
        },
      },
    };
  },
};
```

One of the components:

```
export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
  variant = "primary",
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  if (variant === "primary") return <PrimaryButton {...otherProps} />;
  return <SecondaryButton {...otherProps} />;
};
```

Its story:

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from "@storybook/react";
import React from "react";

import { Button } from "./Button";

export default {
  title: "UI/Button",
  component: Button,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => {
  return <Button {...args}>Button text</Button>;
};

export const Primary = Template.bind({});

export const PrimaryDisabled = Template.bind({});
PrimaryDisabled.args = {
  disabled: true,
};

export const Secondary = Template.bind({});
Secondary.args = {
  variant: "secondary",
};

export const SecondaryDisabled = Template.bind({});
SecondaryDisabled.args = {
  variant: "secondary",
  disabled: true,
};
```

I tried to use default export for the component. It didn't work either.

Comment: For me the problems was about the title and the export. Making `export const Button () => {}`  `export default Button` after that, and  and `export Button from './'` in Story (without brackets) works for me.

Comment: Can you double check all of your imports in `.storybook/preview.js`? I encountered this because I was trying to import something incorrectly in that file, like `import MyComponent` instead of `import { MyComponent }`.